# Jobjects on top of existing object

Tags: java, image, jframe

so I would like to know if it's possible to put things like buttons, text boxes, words, progress bars, ect, ect, on top of an already existing, in this example, JLabel.
Here is the image of the undercoated frame I made, followed by the snippet of code that is associated with this undercoated  frame.

(I dont have 10 reputation, so here is a link to a photo)

> http://prntscr.com/15516f

```
Map.setTitle("Map");
Map.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Map.setUndecorated(true);
Map.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
Map.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JLabel Background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Map.png")));
  Background.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      initialClick = e.getPoint();
      getComponentAt(initialClick);
    }
  });
  Background.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
      // get location of Window
      int thisX = Map.getLocation().x;
      int thisY = Map.getLocation().y;
      // Determine how much the mouse moved since the initial click
      int xMoved = (thisX + e.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
      int yMoved = (thisY + e.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);
      // Move window to this position
      int X = thisX + xMoved;
      int Y = thisY + yMoved;
      Map.setLocation(X, Y);
    }
});
Map.add(Background);
Map.setSize(507,512);
Map.setLocation(0, 100);
Map.setResizable(false);
Map.setVisible(false);
```

on a side note, and I KNOW this is `FlowLayout()`, but when I try to add something else, it'll just put itself above, or below my map.
I'd just like to know if I could put things on top of this Map.
Maybe I should put the image in in another way besides the `JLabel`?

Comment: I Found a solution.
JLabel is a Container, so it can accept a component.
So, I just added:
'Background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
Background.add(objects)'

Thanks

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this seems more logical then using a Label.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`JLayeredPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html) and similar strategies.  See [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more details.

[image]